# Lodash Reduce with Typescript - No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript, lodash

New to Typscript..

Trying to do a simple reduce using Lodash,

```
let collectionScenes: IScene[] = reduce(
  scenes,
  (prev, scene) =>
    scene.collectionId === action.collectionId
      ? prev.push(scene)
      : prev,
  [],
)
```

Having this meltdown:

```
(19,41): No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 6, '(collection: IScene[], callback: MemoListIterator<IScene, any[], IScene[]>, accumulator: any[]): any[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'IKeyArray<IScene>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScene[]'.
      Type 'IKeyArray<IScene>' is missing the following properties from type 'IScene[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
  Overload 2 of 6, '(collection: List<IScene>, callback: MemoListIterator<IScene, any[], List<IScene>>, accumulator: any[]): any[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'IKeyArray<IScene>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List<IScene>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'IKeyArray<IScene>' but required in type 'List<IScene>'.
  Overload 3 of 6, '(collection: IKeyArray<IScene>, callback: MemoObjectIterator<IScene, any[], IKeyArray<IScene>>, accumulator: any[]): any[]', gave the following error.
    Type 'number | any[]' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

Can anyone let me know what this error is about and how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure I get the error, however, it may be related to the problem you have in your code - when you return `prev.push(scene)` that is going to return a *number*, not the array. I think you mean `[...prev, scene]`

Comment: @VLAZ bingo! put that as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your reducer:

```
(prev, scene) =>
  scene.collectionId === action.collectionId
   ? prev.push(scene)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   : prev
```

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns a *number*. It's the new length of the array:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr.push("d"));
console.log(arr.push("e"));
```

So, on the next iteration of `reduce`, the value of the accumulator `prev` would be equal to that number *not* to an array.

You need to *add* a value and still return an array:

```
prev.push(scene);
return prev;
```

But since this is cumbersome in a conditional operator, you can make the addition a single expression if you use:

#### [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
(prev, scene) =>
  scene.collectionId === action.collectionId
   ? prev.concat(scene)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   : prev
```

#### [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
(prev, scene) =>
  scene.collectionId === action.collectionId
   ? [...prev, scene]
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   : prev
```